# Angularjs ui-router with Materialize-angular issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, materialize, angularjs-1.7

I want to use ui-router and angular-materialize together, but when I want to add angular materialize module, it show me this error in console :

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] ...

script.js

```
var routerApp = angular.module("routerApp", ["ui.router"], ['ui.materialize']);

routerApp.controller('mainCtrl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.select = {
            value: "Option1",
            choices: ["Option1", "I'm an option", "This is materialize", "No, this is Patrick."]
        };

routerApp.config(
   ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
      function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

         $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/template1");

         $stateProvider
            .state("template1", {
               url: "/template1",
               templateUrl: "template1.html",
               controller: "tmp1Controller"
            })
            .state("template2", {
               url: "/template2",
               templateUrl: "template2.html",
               controller: "tmp2Controller"
            });
      }
   ]);

routerApp.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope",
   function ($scope) {

   }
]);
routerApp.controller("tmp1Controller", ["$scope",
   function ($scope) {

   }
]);

routerApp.controller("tmp2Controller", ["$scope",
   function ($scope) {

   }
]);
```

Please show me what is my wrong. Here is my code in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zRYV3ZzPXiaf7ZC11s8X?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the wrong syntax that you are using in module definition. It should be

```
var routerApp = angular.module("routerApp", ["ui.router", "ui.materialize"]);
```

which means that the dependencies for the modules are specified as elements of array as second argument to module definition not as different arrays i-e not as `["ui.router"], ['ui.materialize']` but like `["ui.router", "ui.materialize"]`